# Speech to text recognition after some actions

Tags: javascript

How to run recognition with array of songs? Song -> Recognition -> Song -> Recognition -> ... For example, I run the song, then voice recognition starts, then it waits till it finishes and another song runs? Right now I run recognition after the first song but the next song starts playing at the same time.

```
document.getElementById('btnPlay').addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    song.src = songs[currentSong]
    song.play()
})

song.addEventListener('ended', ()=>{

    // recognition starts

    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
        var last = event.results.length - 1;
        var command = event.results[last][0].transcript;
        message.textContent = command + '.';
    }
    recognition.start();

    //I suppose something should be added here to wait when recognition finishes

    currentSong++
    if(currentSong>=songs.length) return
    song.src = songs[currentSong]
    song.play()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the *recognition.onsoundstart()* event to experiment with. I also think you can benefit from the *onsoundend()* event and with them together achieve the workflow you wish for.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/onsoundstart
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/onsoundend

I'm thinking something such as this, spelled in psuedo-code.

- -> Song begins
- --> Listener starts
- ----> song ends
- -----> Listener ends
- -----> On event, start new song and then call *.start()* again.

Answer (score 0):

I just have to start next song when recognition finishes `recognition.addEventListener('end', ()=>{ ...`